# HTML automatically rotating images on render

Tags: html, image, rotation

Can someone help me here. I have a PHP script which uploads an image and resizes it, and then an HTML page which displays the image. However, for some reason the HTML is rendering a rotated version of the image, although I can't for the life of me see why.

```html
<div style="height:75px;width: 116px; background: url(http://viralsmods.com/pokeroulette/content/images/7.jpg);"></div>
```

Run the above snippet to see it in action. The image it is linked to is here: http://viralsmods.com/pokeroulette/content/images/7.jpg.

Any idea on why this could be?

Comment: What about the exif?

Comment: I looked at the image. Try switching your width and height numbers. I think you have those backwards.

Comment: Dimensions were just random for the example. But it shouldn't change the orientation right?

Mindastic: How would one go about doing that, and what would one look for?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to EXIF (Exchangeable Image File Format) and the web browser

Basically, EXIF is a standard for holding file info such as which way an image should be rotated.  Photos taken with (older) devices that do not use EXIF may not appear correctly in your web broswer.

The solution is to bring this file into photoshop, rotate as needed, save, then reupload for your site.

Comment: Hmm, very weird, as it appears correctly in windows file explorer and photos are taken on an HTC one M8 (very recent). Is there a way of modifying the exif headers via PHP (all photos already taken and it'll be very tedious to PS them all).

Comment: Here's an [article that lists lots of options for editing EXIF data](http://www.labnol.org/software/exif-data-editors/14210/).  If you prefer sticking to PS, you can always use the [Image Processor](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html#convert_files_with_the_image_processor) to edit lots of images at once.